# JNLP MIME setting for Lotus Domino server

Tags: java, lotus-notes, jnlp

I am a Java developer and trying to implement the Java Web Start for my application on Lotus Domino server. Though I have referred to [Mapping MIME types to file extensions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_MAPPING_MIME_TYPES_TO_FILE_EXTENSIONS_OVERVIEW.html), I could not understand the information.  The MIME type which I want to add to the server `application/x-java-jnlp-file JNLP`

Could anyone tell me how to do the MIME setting for Domino server?

Comment: The information you found about File Identification documents in the Domino Directory applies to the MIME types of email attachments.  The httpd.cnf file is used for the MIME types in Domino web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to make the change in httpd.cnf in the Domino data folder, which stores MIME type mappings for file-system files served up by Domino's HTTP task.

See this post for more info on achieving this for a different MIME type:

http://www.bananahome.com/users/bananahome/blog.nsf/d6plinks/PSTL-79DS3E